# MySQL Query works in SQL but not PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table called HWC that I want to get a random row through, my database has about 10k entries and the method I was using before went way too slow.

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM HWC AS r1 JOIN
   (SELECT (RAND() *
                 (SELECT MAX(id)
                    FROM HWC)) AS id)
    AS r2 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Here is the Error I get in PHP:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM HWC AS r1 JOIN (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM HWC)) AS id) A' at line 2

SELECT * FROM (`SELECT` * FROM HWC AS r1 JOIN (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM HWC)) AS id) AS r2 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id ORDER BY r1.id ASC LIMIT 1)
```

My Full PHP Code for the model:

```
function random()
{
$query = "SELECT *
FROM HWC AS r1 JOIN
   (SELECT (RAND() *
                 (SELECT MAX(id)
                    FROM HWC)) AS id)
    AS r2 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1";
$result = $this->db->get($query);

return $result->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Given your response to John Conde's answer, you might want to show us the line(s) of php code used create the sql statement and the call you use to execute it.

Comment: Doh answered my own problem, it wasn't the query at all it was the get statement should've been a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My get() should've been a query(); working perfect and FAST now.

Answer (score 0):

Take the ticks off of the second `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM HWC ...
```

Comment: There aren't any, I see that it's changing it in the error but they don't have them in the code. I threw in the PHP code above.